# How to add multiple checkboxes data to MySQL database using PHP PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
try {
    $qry = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM school_periods WHERE account_id = :a_id");
    $qry->execute(array(':a_id'=>$_SESSION['user_account']));
    $qry->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    while($row = $qry->fetch()) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td width='35%'><input type='checkbox' name='periods' value=''></td>
            <td width='35%'><?=$row->period_name; ?></td>
            <td width='35%'><?=$row->start; ?>  </td>
            <td><?=$row->end; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

If the user checks the number of the checkbox, I want to add the checkbox name and value in the database. I tried to achieve this as follows:

```
<?php                
    $schoolyear = $_REQUEST['schoolyear'];
    $start = $_REQUEST['start'];
    $end = $_REQUEST['end'];
    $start = date2mysql($start);
    $end = date2mysql($end);
    $holiday = $_POST['holiday'];
    $status = 1;
    $test = 0;
    if ($test == 1) {
        echo $schoolyear;
        echo '<br />';
        echo $start;
        echo '<br />';
        echo $end;
        echo '<br />';
        echo $status;
        echo '<br />';
        echo $_SESSION['user_account'];
    } 
    try {
        $sqladdyr = "INSERT INTO school_years      (account_id,year_name,start,end,status,added,updated) VALUES (:a_id,:name,:start,:end,:status,NOW(),NOW())";
        $q = $conn->prepare($sqladdyr);
        $q->bindParam(":start", $start, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $q->bindParam(":end", $end, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $q->bindParam(":a_id", $_SESSION['user_account'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $q->bindParam(":name", $schoolyear, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $q->bindParam(":status", $status, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $q->execute();
        $id = $conn->prepare("SELECT MAX('year_id') FROM school_years");  
        //Set needed id.
        $id->execute();
        $id->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        while ($idval = $id->fetch()) {
            $id_val = $idval->year_id;
        }
        foreach ( $holiday as $key => $value ):
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO holidays(account_id,year_id,holiday_name,start) VALUES(:a_id,:yid,:name,:date)");
            $stmt->execute(array(
                ':a_id' => $_SESSION['user_account'],
                'year_id'=>$id_val,
                ':name'=>$_POST['holiday'][$key],
                ':date'=>$_POST['holiday'][$value] // assuming this is the same for all rows?
            ));
        endforeach;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Unfortunately, this does not seem to work. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: now i am able to store values into database. and along with it i want to store dynamic id of each selected box what should i do? please help me